# how to extract string before and after comma in R

Tags: r, regex

So I have a list of string like this:

```
Woman Killed in Uber Accident in Goleta, California

Sacramento, California Man Dies in Lyft Accident
```

And I wanna the output to be like "Goleta, California". How do I do it? 
Thanks

Comment: What if the woman had been killed in East Orange, New Jersey?

Comment: `gsub(".*?(\\w+,\\s+?\\w+).*", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

With the data you have provided the following will do it. I believe the regex is general purpose.

```
library(stringr)

x <- c("Woman Killed in Uber Accident in Goleta, California",
"Sacramento, California Man Dies in Lyft Accident")

str_extract(x, "(^|[^[:blank:]]*),[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]*|$)")
#[1] "Goleta, California"     "Sacramento, California"
```